# The pointwise limit of functions with uniformly bounded derivatives is Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f_n: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable for
>    each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $|f'_n(x)| \le 1$ for all $n$ and $x$.
>    Let $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) = g(x)$ for all $x$. Prove
>    that $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz-continuous.

What I've tried is writing down all the definitions, but I can't see how they connect to provide a proof.

We know that $\forall \varepsilon>0$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists N$ such that $n \ge N$ implies $|f_n(x) - g(x)| < \varepsilon$. To show that $g$ is Lipschitz-continuous, I need to show that $\exists K>0$ such that $\forall x, z \in \mathbb{R}$, $|g(x) - g(z)| \le K|x-z|$. I can't seem to connect the pieces together and tie in the boundedness on the derivative to complete the proof.

Comment: Hint: are $f_n$ Lipschitz-continuous?

Comment: The function is not pointwise convergent, the sequence $f_n$ is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1. Prove that each $f_n$ is Lipschitz continuous with the same constant $L=1$.

This is an easy consequence of the mean value theorem: given $x < y$, there exists $c\in (x,y)$ such that
$$
|f_n(x) - f_n(y)| = |f_n'(c)| \cdot |x-y| \leq |x-y|.
$$

Step 2. For every fixed $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, by step 1 you have that
$$
|f_n(x) - f_n(y)| \leq |x-y|
\qquad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.
$$
Now it is enough to pass to the limit as $n\to +\infty$, obtaining
$$
|g(x) - g(y)| \leq |x-y|.
$$
(To be precise, you should use the triangular inequality:
$$
\begin{split}
|g(x) - g(y)| & \leq |g(x) - f_n(x)| + |g(y)-f_n(y)| + |f_n(x) - f_n(y)|
\\ & \leq |g(x) - f_n(x)| + |g(y)-f_n(y)| + |x-y|
\end{split}
$$
and then pass to the limit as $n\to +\infty$.)

Comment: Hmm, I'm still a bit confused, do you think you can provide a full proof based on your hints? Thank you very much.

Comment: why the use of the triangle inequality? It is not enough to know that $|{\cdot}|$ is continuous in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @Masacroso: yes, it is enough, but if you want to prove it you have to use the triangle inequality.