# Proof for the pointwise limit of functions with bounded derivatives being Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification, lipschitz-functions

Let $f_n\colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable for
 each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\lvert f'_n(x)\rvert \le 1$ for all $n$ and $x$.
 Let $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) = g(x)$ for all $x$. Prove
 that $g\colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz-continuous.

I know one can prove this using the triangle inequality, e.g. as suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2379793/the-pointwise-limit-of-functions-with-uniformly-bounded-derivatives-is-lipschitz). I wanted to check if the following, similar argument is also valid:

Let $x$,$y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n$ be arbitrary. By the mean value theorem, there exists $c \in (x,y)$ such that
$$ f_n(x)-f_n(y)= f_n^{'}(c) \cdot (x-y).$$
Using this, we obtain a bound for the differential quotient of $f_n(x)$:
$$\frac{\mid f_n(x)-f_n(y)\mid}{\mid x-y \mid} = \frac{\mid f_n^{'}(c)\mid \cdot\mid x-y \mid}{\mid x-y \mid} \leq 1.$$ 
Therefore, we obtain the following:
$$\frac{\mid g(x)-g(y)\mid}{\mid x-y \mid} = \frac{\mid \lim f_n(x)- \lim f_n(y)\mid}{\mid x-y \mid} =\frac{\mid \lim (f_n(x)-f_n(y))\mid}{\mid x-y \mid} = \lim\frac{\mid f_n(x)-f_n(y)\mid}{\mid x-y \mid} \leq 1 ,$$
where the first equality follows by definition, the second by limit laws for addition, the third as $\mid {}\cdot{}\mid$ is continuous and the inequality as if a convergent sequence is bounded, then the limit is bounded in the same way.

Comment: To me, it is fine.

Comment: I think it's ok. Perhaps, I would have called the $c$ in the mean value theorem $c_n$, since there is one for each $n$, not necessarily the same each time. But that doesn't compromise the rest of the proof, and if you see it as 'I fixed an $n$, I proved for that $n$ that the quotient is less than one and then I forgot about $c$; now I affirm that the argument is general and thus the inequality is true for every $n$', I think that's fine too.